# Electron app becomes blank whenever I reload

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm making an electron app however it my page turns blanks whenever I reload it - with `Ctrl + R`. The developer tools becomes blank as well and it shows the following error -

```
Devtools was disconnected from the page

Once page is reloaded DevTools will automatically reconnect
```

**This is my package.json**

```
{
  "name": "pla",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "T",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3"
  },
  "author": "R",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "custom-electron-titlebar": "^3.2.4",
    "electron": "^10.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "knex": "^0.21.6",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-rebuild": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

**Initialise devtools**

```
// Add developer tools item if not in production

if (process.env.NODE_ENV != "production") {
    mainMenuTemplate.push({
        label: "Developer Tools",
        submenu: [
            {
                label: "Toggle Devtools",
                accelerator: process.platform == "darwin" ? "command+I" : "Ctrl+I",

                click(item, focusedWindow) {
                    focusedWindow.toggleDevTools();
                },
            },
            {
                role: "reload",
            },
        ],
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code? Especially the part where you initialise the devtools

Comment: @Tasos Bu I've added that. Please let me know if you require any other relevant code. I'm not sure why this is happening so I'm not sure which part of the code I should provide. I would also like to add that I have 2 screen.. If that can be a cause for this issue